# MVC 404 Errors - Still New

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, http-status-code-404

So, I'm getting a 404 error on my current MVC project on submit. I'm new to MVC, so I'm likely doing something exceptionally stupid. Here's the relevant code...

```
<%@ Page Title="Pies" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" MasterPageFile="~/site.master" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h1>Oh Boy Pies</h1>
<p>Tell us about the pies!</p>
<form action="Process" method="post">
    <div class="inputdiv">
        <span class="spaced">Name:</span>
        <%= Html.TextBox("name") %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("name", "*") %>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the relevant handler is...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;

namespace tabdemo.Controllers
{
     public class HomeController : Controller
     {
         public ActionResult Index ()
         {
            ViewData ["Message"] = "Demo!";
            return View ();
         }
         public ActionResult Process (FormCollection form)
         {
            Response.Write (form ["name"]);
            Response.End ();
            return Redirect ("Index.aspx");
         }
     }
}
```

Also, can people explain how this would be implemented using TextBoxFor, for example? I've seen examples of it, but I don't understand it at all.

edit: Here's the masterpage

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 </head>
 <body>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing ASP.NET Webforms with MVC?

Comment: `Response.Write()` and `Response.End()` are likely causing problems. What are you trying to accomplish in your `Process` action?

Comment: Switch to MVC4, get a good book on it and start using the latest Razor syntax. The problem is probably that you're a seasoned Webforms developer trying to learn MVC(1 or 2, just maybe 3).

Comment: @Aniket I may be mistaken, but I believe that's proper MVC syntax using the original (pre-Razor) view engine.

Comment: Actually, I'm not a webforms developer at all. Never used them - not once. I'm a PHP developer more used to building the HTML and a processing page separately and such. I'm used to writing all my inputs with actual real HTML, rather than having some external force build them for me =/. I'm being forced to learn C# MVC though and that's what the examples were using x.x.

Comment: I am not worried about the Webforms view engine, what I am worried about is the Controller bit, do you have Process.aspx and Index.aspx in the Views/Home folder of your project or Views/Shared folder?

Comment: Err, I don't have Process.aspx in my home folder, no. I do have Index.aspx. What exactly should go in my process.aspx file if the controller for my index.aspx view has the Process function? I'm a bit confused, I'm sorry.

Comment: @LaniAlden that's alright, which tutorials are you referring? online or in your company?

Comment: @LaniAlden did you try to use `return RedirectToAction("Index");` instead of the three `Response` lines?

Comment: @Aniket I am using random ones on the internet. I haven't found any that have been sufficiently helpful though. Most seem to think you understand the MVC model going into MVC. I did try that and it did nothing to fix the error.

Comment: clearly Index.aspx isn't in the correct path.

Comment: what MVC version are you using?

Comment: Erm, MVC3. Do I need a Process.aspx or no? I know if I were coding this in PHP-land I'd need to just write that separately and all would be well, but the MVC seems to not like writing additional pages.

Comment: No you don't need a process.aspx, you have Process() method in your controller.

Comment: @LaniAlden post your Directory structure of the project. I am assuming the index.aspx is in a wrong place, or unreachable.

Comment: Mmk... Please take a look at http://s14.postimage.org/ifen85ui9/mvc.jpg

Comment: @LaniAlden hmm, I see a weird problem in your html now..

Comment: Change action="Process" to action="/Home/Process"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `return RedirectToAction("Index")`. MVC does not use PAGES, instead relies on `Controller` to route the request.

Controllers return the View, or Redirect to another Controller, which renders the view.

**EDIT**
And yes, the action method was incorrect(just saw)

```
<form action="/Home/Process" method="post">
    <div class="inputdiv">
        <span class="spaced">Name:</span>
        <%= Html.TextBox("name") %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("name", "*") %>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @LaniAlden you're welcome :) and yes, get MVC4 and start using Razor. Webforms View engine is horrible imho.

Comment: I'm not a fan either, so I will. It's all the same to me x.x. Then again I like writing my own HTML and keeping these boxes terribly separate and bleh.

Comment: the HTML helpers will get you going, and reduce these sorts of errors.

Comment: As a morale booster, Stack Overflow is written in MVC4 and uses the Razor engine to render the web application. :-) @LaniAlden